# what should I set a mac's permissions with party App

Tags: macos, permissions, installation

what should I set a mac's permissions to be so that every user can use a third party app (in my case, QuarkXPress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything special with permissions - so long as the application is installed in `/Applications` and not say, `/Users/someone/Applications`, then it's accessible to all users on the system.

Comment: As long as it has permissions of at least 755.

Comment: Something like Quark XPress surely comes with an installer that sets the required permissions.